# How to get text from online .txt file quickly? (c#)

Tags: c#, text, updates

I'm trying to make a very simple updater app that reads current version.txt file contents and checks if it's the same or greater (in which case update starts).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169982/http-get-request-and-xml-answer) helped me make a working app, but it causes a significant pause in my main app. Could it work faster or is there an easier way to load text from online .txt file?

UPD: for some reason the ~15 second lag only happens at first run, all consequent `DownloadString`s work as fast as they should until the app is closed.

Comment: Can you run it as an asynchronous request whilst you're doing something else?

Comment: I would rather not do it, or it can look like the app is up to date, user starts working and after some time he gets notification that the version is outdated and all progress made will be incompatible with current version.

Comment: 'after some time' will probably be within a few seconds, won't it? Do you have a splash screen - can you run it asynchronously with your splash screen? If the delay is loading the wininet engine then you could instead just make a socket call to the web server with a simple HTTP request in it and avoid wininet, but then you'd have to deal with proxy servers etc. yourself which wininet just handles for you.

Comment: No splash screens, the app opens and the user starts work instantly. It's about fifteen seconds, the time varies, and changing things within the app while the version is being downloaded could do nothing if it's outdated. Also I don't have any idea what you mean, could you write an example?

Comment: Won't you also have the same problem if a user keeps a client running whilst you update the server - they'll be working with an out-of-date incompatible client? How do you solve that one? OK, I'll try and write something.

Comment: How long does something like client.DownloadString("http:///www.google.com/index.html") take? (Note, there is only supposed to be two blackslashes before the www.google.com)

Comment: What happens if you use 173.194.66.103 instead of www.google.com ?

Comment: Excatly the same. I don't think it's about resolving.

Comment: Strange. I tested this in Linqpad and it took about 300 ms. Can you test this on another computer or outside your network?

Comment: Other computers show the same result. First press of the button takes ~15 seconds and consequent presses are near instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pause was caused by default proxy settings. Solution is in my other question:

[WebClient.DownloadString takes about 15 seconds when first called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568321/webclient-downloadstring-takes-about-15-seconds-when-first-called)

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to magically make the download faster. Instead, I recommend you execute the download on a separate thread so the user can use your app without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
```

And what do you mean the *significant pause*?
Is the response time of the server you tried to fetch .txt file?

Comment: I don't really know what exactly causes the pause, because the host from which the text file is fetched is fast and the file itself is very small.

Comment: Either you didn't pin point the write location of your "delay" or else your connection is simply slow. Try to measure where the "delay" happens.

Comment: `DownloadFile` works as slowly as `DownloadString`, unfortunately. I can't figure out where the delay is coming from. VS profiler doesn't show performance spikes or anything, it just hangs for some time, that's it.

Comment: Because they are the same thing basically. And I am curious about how long does it hangs?

Comment: 13 to 15 seconds by `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to make you app faster:

- If you are using winforms, try to use console application (it will do things really fast for this case).
- If you want to use winforms, try to use workers to do some process in behind and don't block the user to interact with your app. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Why would a console application make a webclient request faster than a forms app?

Comment: @Rup Not exactly a webclient request, everything. But for some cases this is useful (console apps) for others not, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628164/do-console-apps-run-faster-than-gui-apps

Comment: [But the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628228) says they generally don't, doesn't it? Would message loop processing really have a significant impact on a web request?

Comment: @Rup read carefully the long answer of the accepted answer and for this case I think that can be used because it is just a simple app that captures texts from the net.

Comment: While the request is being handled, the app hangs (form stops redrawing) anyway.

Comment: @user1306322 that's why a console app is faster (for doing things as you want and avoid redrawing) but If you read the explanation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628164/do-console-apps-run-faster-than-gui-apps "a console application would still be contending for the CPU with other processes in the system".

Comment: I don't get it — while getting the file, the app stops redrawing automatically, so the redrawing does not consume resources while the main process of this question is being run. Redrawing itself doesn't consume any significant amount of resources. I'm not sure if it's on-topic.

Comment: @user1306322 Try making a console app in c# and see the difference.

Comment: @OscarJara exactly the same time as forms app — 13 seconds.

Comment: @user1306322 that's because you're blocking the UI thread - you should do non-UI work on a background thread

Comment: No, I disagree - it's simply waiting on a socket so the little UI overhead mentioned in the long answer won't cause a user-perceivable slow-down